# StackOverflow Time Limits?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Ban myself” button in user profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32299/ban-myself-button-in-user-profiles)

Hi there,

I thought of this question as I was answering a question on StackOverflow at 3 in the morning.

I came to the realization that I am **addicted** to StackOverflow. And I'm sure that I'm not the only one.

I'm hereby requesting that SO have a **voluntary lockout** feature. Please?

Anyway, I want to take this opportunity to say "thank you" to the wonderful community and moderators here on SO. You guys are awesome!