# SO Addict salvage feature - voluntarily give up login for X days

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   ["Ban myself" button in user profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32299/ban-myself-button-in-user-profiles)

*"Stack Overflow does suck. It sucks you in and it is impossible to escape"*
  -- [James McNellis comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93357/stack-overflow-sucks)

I feel in my own bones this can be true ;-) I'm [apparently not the only one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11115/you-know-youve-been-browsing-stack-overflow-too-much-when), and while I realize that the issue is slightly funny (please take this post not too seriously), I have a strong feeling that some kind of solution would be really helpful to many of us :-)

> **Proposal**: allow the user to voluntarily give up login for X days (X can be selected,
>   up to some value - say 7 days).

The user would not be allowed to login during that time. However, his rep could be increased as other users vote for his posts. If he needs to search for some problem solutions, he can browse the site anonymously.

The problem might arise when he needs to ask question he really needs to do his work. 
Personally, I wouldn't mind to ignore this issue. It was my decission to give up. But one might invent solutions like unlocking the account after 4 hours from request just for adding 1-2 questions. However, it's not needed by my opinion - keep it simple.

> You may argue that is personal issue of everyone, but - *why not allow
>   this, if not only is it possible, but also simple and working?*
>
> **Please don't downvote if you don't agree! You just don't need to use
>   this feature.**

Comment: This is a neat idea, +1.

Comment: "This user has been placed in timed suspension to **get a life**. The suspension period ends in seven days" .. status.completed.

Comment: @EatmoreTwisters: You *would* say that :)

Comment: @Nick Dandoulakis: I see, thanks. 2 yrs old discussion though, let the discussion run again to see how it evolved :-)

Comment: *"The user would not be allowed to login during that time. However, his rep could be increased as other users vote for his posts."* Maybe you didn't notice, but **the exact same thing happens if you just *don't login*.** Kind of stifles the need for this "feature request". Also, -1 for "please don't downvote".

Comment: @Cody Gray: you know my point very well, don't pretend you don't, I couldn't have been clearer. Now *I can* login, but *I want I couldn't*.

Comment: `"Please don't downvote if you don't agree"` um, no.

Comment: @Tomas: I don't really get your point. Do you really lack so much self control that you can't stop yourself from logging into a website? Perhaps you should seek help outside of the Stack Overflow team. It wasn't a clarity problem, it was a *nonsense* problem.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Yes I do. Otherwise I wouldn't request this feature :-) Single button would solve the problem (not only for me) and wouldn't hurt anyone, so why do you mind?

Comment: Have someone change your password and then give it to you 7 days later.  Or learn some self-control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could always fine-tune it so that you ban yourself only from answering questions, but not from asking them, or commenting, for example.

And how about chat?

The question afterwards is would this be for just one site, or network-wide?

Comment: well, I think the ban could be network wide for the whole SO/SE bunch of sites (may be optional). Regarding the 1st paragraph - didn't you mean "..., but not from asking them"? Anyway, I would prefer to ban everything, include commenting.

Comment: @Tomas, thanks, yes. As regards *what* to ban, I think the user is the only person who knows what is addictive for them. Not everyone is addicted to just rep.